# QuickSight controller doens't update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

On quicksight I have a dashboard, using direct query, connect to a table on data catalog

I have a **"continent"** field and I use a **controller** to filter the data, however, after update that field with new data and updated the dataset, the controller keep showing the old data...

The data shows as it should on Athena and the other charts but even if I create a new controller it keeps showing only the older data.

I appreciate in advance for all the help.

Comment: is the dataset spice enabled?  SPICE will cache the data and you'll need to refresh it

Comment: I think it might be that, is it possible to uneable it or, since I'm using controllers, it really needs tha SPICE?